# How do I run the drush tests in docker?

Tags: drush

I'm trying to improve drush, and the [drush contributing guidelines](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/11.x/docs/contribute/unish.md) state:

> Drush's own tests may be run within provided Docker containers (see
> docker-compose.yml):
>
> Start containers: docker-compose up -d

So I forked Drush on Github, cloned the repo locally, and then, from the repo root, ran `docker-composer up -d`.  This gives an error:

> ERROR:
> Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
> parent. Are you in the right directory?

So then I tried to find the right directory by searching for a `docker-compose.yml`, but I can't find it anywhere.  I searched the Drush repo on GitHub as well but I couldn't find it there, either.

How do I launch `docker-compose` to run the drush tests?

Comment: It's still there in [10.x](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/10.x/docker-compose.yml), but got removed by [291c8eb](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/commit/291c8eb61cd6278fcf327cb90b00b81139728f71), issue [#4915](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/4915)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've started using DDEV instead of direct docker-compose. [Docs now updated](https://www.drush.org/latest/contribute/unish/). Thanks for the report